# Why do the datasheets of LMH6702 and ADC08200 have different bypass capacitors in the example designs?

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc

The datasheet for the LMH6702 recommends using 6.8uF bypass capacitors on both power supply pins.  The example design in the datasheet of the ADC08200 (Fig. 33 on page 17) instead suggests a 0.1uF capacitor.  Why is there a difference choice?  Which datasheet should I follow?

Comment: Toby you also need the 0.01uF for >20MHz and 100 pF for 1GHz but latter is often done in layout

Comment: Layout is critical and controlled impedance on all traces

Answer (score 3):

The [LMH6702](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6702.pdf) can slew its output *very* quickly into a low impedance load and as such [bulk bypass](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/170957/de-coupling-capacitor-and-bulk-capacitor) is required for low impedance load applications in addition to the higher frequency decoupling capacitors. The application shown is generic for any load and has both the bulk bypass *and* 0.1\$\mu F\$ bypass devices.

The [ADC08200](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snas136m/snas136m.pdf) has a high impedance input (with the attendant low output current from the LMH6702 used in the application example) and as such does not require the bulk bypass.

Answer (score 1):

These are two entirely different chips with entirely different functions. There's no reason you should expect their bypassing recommendations will be the same.

> Why is there a difference choice?

It could be the chips have different on-chip capacitance, leading one to being less sensitive to high-frequency supply noise.

It could be that one chip generates more digital switching noise than the other.

It could just be that the guy who wrote one datasheet has a different interpretation of what are "best practices" than the other.

> Which datasheet should I follow?

There's no reason you can't follow both. Put a 6.8 uF capacitor near the power supply pins of the LMH6702 and a 0.1 uF capacitor near the supply pins of the ADC08200.

For the op-amp, I'd recommend to consider the actual signal frequencies you'll be putting through the device in your design, and choose your bypass capacitor accordingly.

For the ADC, I'd recommend following the datasheet.